# youtube API 3 - get all data in single request

Tags: api, video, youtube

I am using YouTube API 3 to fetch video results for which I have to make two http requests which are sequential not parallel.

1- First API call is to get  youtube video ids for a search term.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=video&q=QUERY_TERM&key={API KEY}

2- From first I am preparing a list of comma separated video IDs (ALL_VIDEO_IDS) and fetching individual video details like duration, viewcount etc.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=ALL_VIDEO_IDS&part=contentDetails,statistics&key={API KEY}

Actually I want a way so that I can get all these details in one call rather than two. How to achieve this?

Is there a way to achieve it which I don't know or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here it is, with example of getting video duration,
but do not forget to create your API key at https://console.developers.google.com/project

```
$vidkey = "cHPMH2sa2Q" ; video key for example 
$apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" ;

$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$vidkey&key=$apikey");
$VidDuration =json_decode($dur, true);
foreach ($VidDuration['items'] as $vidTime) 
{
$VidDuration= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
```